# creating new bindingContext to be used by children view models

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I have 2 custom controls `parent-control` and `child-control`. I need child to execute functionalities on behalf of the parent. and the requirement is that child should be used within parent boundaries.

**usage example**

```
...<content-around> <!-- this is 'outerContext' bindingContext -->
  <parent-control shared.bind="outerContext.something">
    <div>
      <child-control property="nameOfMemberOfShared"></child-control>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>some text here</span>
      <child-control property="anotherNameOfMemberOfShared"></child-control>
    </div>
  </parent-control>
</content-around>...
```

---

**parent-control.html**

```
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

---

**parent-control.ts** (assuming all the imports)

```
export class ParentControlCustomElement {
  @bindable shared: any;

  bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
    //here want to make sure elements rendered inside slot 
    //are able to access 'shared'
  }
}
```

---

**child-control.html**

```
<template>
  <!-- this is for simplicity more advanced stuff needed here -->
  <h1>${sharedObject[property]}</h1>
</template>
```

---

**child-control.ts** (assuming all imports)

```
export class ChildControlCustomElement {
  @bindable property: string;
  sharedObject: any;

  bind(bindingContext, overrideContext) {
    this.sharedObject = bindingContext.shared;
    // the problem is HERE!
    // instead of getting a binding context pointing 
    // to parent-control view model I get binding context
    // pointing to 'outerContext'
  }
}
```

How can I make sure that starting at `parent-control` inner components will get a binding context pointing to `parent-control`'s view model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know your child control will always be used within the parent control you can declare a dependency on the ancestor/parent:

```
@inject(ParentControlCustomElement)
export class ChildControlCustomElement {
  constructor(parentControl) {
    this.parentControl = parentControl;
  }
}
```

If it you don't know for sure whether the child control will be used within the parent, use `@inject(Optional.of(ParentControlCustomElement))`.

Comment: Interesting, let me give it a try